# Logging a Camel route in Service mix

Tags: logging, error-logging, apache-servicemix

Im using Apache Service Mix 5.4 for deploying camel routes wrapped in maven osgi bundles.

Im working on Logging and Monitoring the camel routes.
Currently while trying like

```
from("timer://javaTimer?fixedRate=true&period=2000")
.bean(transform, "transform")
.to("log:ExampleRouter");
```

the above camel route logs the message in default servicemix.log. 
Is there any other way of configuring the My own logger in servicemix camel  which does sending log message to log file, insert log message into table etc. ????

Found some articles about karaf to make use of own appenders like mentioned in last section of below link
https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/users-guide/logging-system.html

But its not complete. Can someone provide any examples of creating appenders and using in karaf along with camel routes please???

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create your own log file in Service Mix. Go to etc folder under root directory and we will find file org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg. 
update this file and you will have your own logs.

For more information, read the following artical
http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/4.4.x/users-guide/logging-system.html